# How can i generate a random large image file using c# code?

Tags: c#, .net, image

I have a requirement to generate 100s of thousands of random but unique image files (.jpeg/tiff/png) with the following criteria and drop it into a folder of choice :

Generated file to be with a given resolution, size (eg. 100mb each) but can be any dummy randomised colours/patterns etc...

Is there any way i can generate this using c# or any other programming technique ?

Comment: It´s hard to google: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-qltHrbqGE

Comment: I recommend you take a look this post: http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/creating-images-from-scratch-in-c.html and also consider to use GPU instead of CPU.

Comment: Why should **we** do what is assigned to **you**? You have to provide some own affords in order to get help here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere because people tend to face challenges in different analogical terms though the core is same and having answers or atleast directions would benefit users who come across in the future with same requirement but in a different scenario.  Anyways thanks for your kind guidance everyone else. !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code I use in one project to fast generate jpeg image with random "white noise" and specified text (which can also be random) in the middle:

```
    private static void GenerateDummyJpegAt(string outputPath, string nameToEmbed, int width, int height) {
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)) {
            BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
            byte[] noise = new byte[data.Width*data.Height*3];
            new Random().NextBytes(noise); // note that if you do that in a loop or from multiple threads - you may want to store this random in outside variable
            Marshal.Copy(noise, 0, data.Scan0, noise.Length);
            bmp.UnlockBits(data);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
                // draw white rectangle in the middle
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, height/2 - 20, width, 40);
                var fmt = new StringFormat();
                fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                // draw text inside that rectangle
                g.DrawString(nameToEmbed, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), fmt);
            }
            using (var fs = File.Create(outputPath)) {
                bmp.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
GenerateDummyJpegAt(@"G:\tmp\dummy.jpg", "Some random string", 800, 600);
```

Results:

[image]